# WoW: Help with a macro

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was trying to make a macro which will cast a mount out of combat when pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I made this:

```
/cast [modifier:alt][nocombat]Pegaso
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean when you just press alt or do you mean when you press alt and something else or alt and click on a button? As it is the two conditionals you have say that you must be holding alt and you must be in combat when you activate the macro. The latter at least is not what you want. See https://wow.gamepedia.com/Macro_conditionals for more info on these conditionals.

Comment: I'm just trying to summon a mount. I made a mistake, semicolons are used to separate actions. But, I have to use /cast or /use to summon the mount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `,` to combine multiple conditions in `[]`:

```
#showtooltip
/cast [mod:alt,nocombat]Pegaso
```

You can see many examples at [this wiki](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Macro_conditionals#Conditional_target).

Comment: You got the idea. But, I have to use /cast or /use to summon the mount?

Comment: `/cast` and `/use` are the same thing - look at the aliases at the [`/cast` wiki](https://wow.gamepedia.com/MACRO_cast)